# Shutdown Computer if UPS Battery is Low 22.04

Tags: 22.04, power-management, shutdown, battery

I have a UPS connected via USB and under Settings->Power I am able to see the UPS battery percentage, however there is no option for telling the computer what action to take if the UPS battery gets low.

On earlier versions, I am currently using 22.04, I was able to set an option to shut the computer down if battery became critical. However now the option no longer exists. Is there something I need to install to make this option available?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at nut, "network ups tools".

Comment: https://www.linux.com/news/smart-power-monitoring-network-ups-tools/

Comment: I have installed and am playing with "nut" and I can use "upsc" to see info on the ups but now the ups is not showing up in power settings at all and ups battery level no longer shows in my status bar

Comment: This is a good guide that i use. https://wiki.ipfire.org/addons/nut/detailed

Comment: Also see if nut works for your ups. https://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html

Comment: Try "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true" to show batt %

Comment: So I played with nut, and got it working but it did not show up in my settings dialog... it was a bit more than what I need, feature wise,  but not what I wanted which was a configuration option in "settings:. I just want to set something like I do on my laptop to shutdown the computer. I can already see the battery percentage... I am just looking to add "shutdown computer when battery is critical" option.... I am thinking I might need "laptop mode utilities" installed... I am gong to try that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really a fan of the overly simplified update that was made to the power settings GUI, and the only way I could find to change these settings in Ubuntu 20.04 was with dconf-editor.

In dconf-editor, you can try going to:

```
/ org / gnome / settings-daemon / plugins / power
```

And change the critical-battery-action to 'shutdown'.

You can also change the percentage-critical from the default of 3% to something a little more conservative, like 10%. This will give your computer a little more time to power down.

Test it out and let me know how it goes. I recently made the same changes on my computer, so hopefully this does the trick. If you found this helpful, please consider an up-vote. If you find a better way to fix this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but there was no "shutdown" option. I have laptop mode utils already installed... There must be something I need but I don't know what

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 22.04 as stated in OP

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:  https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/change-battery-critical-low-action-ubuntu-18-04/

I know the link says 18.04 but has been updated for 22.04.

I'll summarize it here in case the link goes bad.

1. Open /etc/UPower/UPower.conf in your favorite editor
2. Change CriticalPowerAction to the desired value (PowerOff/Hibernate/HybridSleep)

Comment: This looks like it might work. I am on 23.10 and still need to connect my UPS via USB to my new computer but as soon as I test it I will let you know. Thanks!!!!